# bar plot - annotate the bars with some values

Tags: pandas, plot, annotations

Immediately after creating a bar plot using pandas dataframe.plot function, I am trying to annotate the bars with some values that I have in a list. I have put the annotate command in a for loop. But, as soon as I run this piece of code, my ipython notebook stops working and it crashes.

When I remove the annotation part, the bar plot works fine. What could be the reason for this?

```
req_index = df.index[~df.index.isin(['99'])]

ax = df.ix[req_index,'count'].plot(kind="barh", figsize=(24,20), \
                                        color = (0.10588235294117647, 0.6196078431372549, 0.4666666666666667))

y_values = ax.get_yticks().astype('int')

for i,indx in enumerate(req_index):
    label_text = str(round(df.ix[indx,'percentage'], 4))
    print label_text
    x = df.ix[indx,'count']
    y = y_values[i]
    ax.annotate(label_text, xy = (x + 70000,y-3), size = 20)
    #break
```

Comment: Show what you have done ....

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: done.. can u please have a look at it and help me out?